# Azure VNet: Can I Change the Gateway Subnet Range?

Tags: networking, azure, azure-networking

I have read the Microsoft documentation, and I know I can add/edit subnets. But it seems like I can't edit the GatewaySubnet that I created when I created the Gateway for the VNet, without deleting the Gateway. This is problematic for me, as upon re-creation of the Gateway, Azure will assign me a new IP address for that Gateway, which I do not want to do.

Is it possible to modify my current GatewaySubnet?

I have tried using Powershell commands, but I get an error that the subnet is currently in use and can't be modified while in use. I also have not found a way to change the status of a gateway from Active, without the gateway being deleted.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Noah

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a subnet if there are any resources attached to it.

> Address range: If no resources are deployed within the subnet, you can change the address range. If any resources exist in the subnet, you must either move the resources to another subnet, or delete them from the subnet first.

https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-subnet#change-subnet-settings

I guess you have two options, build a new vNET/Subnet with new gateways and switch the traffic over. Or redeploy the current setup with the risk of getting new IPs.

Comment: That's the answer I received from Microsoft. In my case, I didn't want to lost the IP address, but had no choice. Appreciate the validation.